# How to make a 3rd party pay for the RAM

Tags: ram-allocation

In the `eosio.token` contract, the `transfer` action makes the sender pay for the RAM if a new account has to be created for the receiver. I would like to make a contract where is the issuer of the token the one that always pays. What permissions would the issuer need to set in order to allow the table `emplace` method call to receive her as ram payer albeit her not being involved in the current transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 3rd party must be signing the transaction, there is no way to delegate the permission if I'm reading this right

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/3016381ec3a899e19623377d92bd63af534cacfe/libraries/chain/apply_context.cpp#L354

Comment: hello, but I see in the token contract, when I transfer token to others, it will call to_acnts.modify( to, 0, [&]( auto& a ) {
        a.balance += value;
      }); the payer 0 may represent the receiver, but the receiver didn't authorize the transfer, how does it work?

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v1.0.8/libraries/chain/apply_context.cpp#L364 is it because the modify will not add the usage, so we don't need the receiver's permission?

Comment: Exactly. The net RAM usage won’t change

Comment: oh, it's really tricky

Answer (score 0):

So either one of the accounts which have a signature in transaction can pay for RAM (see Ariel's answer), or contract account itself can pay for it. [Source](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-you-define-who-pays-and-who-stores-on-your-smart-contract-tables).